# Find all permutations of a string in C++

Tags: c++, strings, combinatorics

I need a review of the following code for finding all permutations of a string in C++:

```
List Permute(const String& string)
{
    if (string.length == 0)
        return EmptyStrings(1);
    List prevList = Permute(SubString(string,1,string.length));
    List nextList = EmptyStrings(string.length*prevList.length);
    for (int i=0; i<prevList.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<string.length; j++)
        {
            nextList[i*string.length+j] += SubString(prevList[i],0,j);
            nextList[i*string.length+j] += string[0];
            nextList[i*string.length+j] += SubString(prevList[i],j,string.length-1);
        }
    }
    return nextList;
}
```

You may assume the correctness of the following:

```
class List
class String
List EmptyStrings(int n); // returns a list of 'n' empty strings
String SubString(const String& string,int i,int j); // returns the string 'string[i...j)'
```

Comment: This is cheating, but I thought it would be nice to mention that [<algorithm>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/) has useful functions for this such as [next_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/), [prev_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/prev_permutation/), and [is_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/is_permutation/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to remove duplicates. Consider what your output will be if, for example, your input string is `"aaa"`.

---

Code like this is unusual:

```
// nextList contains an array of empty strings
nextList[i*string.length+j] += SubString(prevList[i],0,j);
```

IMO this would be more usual:

```
// nextList is empty
// calculate new string
string nextString = SubString(prevList[i],0,j)
    + string[0]
    + SubString(prevList[i],j,string.length-1);
nextList.Add(nextString);
```

---

Returning by value is sometimes necessary but can be inefficient. Your algorithm creates many temporary List objects. A better API might be ...

```
void Permute(const String& inputString, List& outputList) { ... }
```

... where one empty List is allocated by the caller, and you add to it.

---

This statement may be incorrect ...

```
List prevList = Permute(SubString(string,1,string.length));
```

... I don't know how `returns the string 'string[i...j)'` is defined but perhaps this statement should be ...

```
List prevList = Permute(SubString(string,1,string.length - 1));
```

---

You may run out of memory very quickly. For a string of length `n` there are `n!` ('n factorial') permutations. `"what's up doc?"` has 14 characters => 87178291200 (or 0x144C3B2800) i.e. bigger than 2<sup>32</sup> combinations.

Comment: Never thought of the possibility of duplicates, thanks

Comment: As to the 'run out of memory' - that will obviously happen regardless of how efficient my method is in terms of memory consumption, due to the number of permutations itself

Comment: It's true that [Combinatorial optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization) is a non-trivial problem for computer scientists. Perhaps (I don't know) if you search you'll find (previously researched) algorithms for this "permutations of a string" problem. IMO there might be a solution which can work for larger strings, by generating/outputing the list of permutations to a (larger than 4 GB) output file on disk.

Comment: Returning by value is unlikely to `inefficient`. RVO and NRVO basically prevent the copy from happening (ie it is elided). So prefer to use the more natural style of return by value. Also with move semantics in C++11 it becomes important to use return by value so that these kick in as expected automatically.